# Changing the legend and the style of plots that are displayed by Show?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, legending

I have a function two variables (which is not z t^2) that requires a lot of processing to plot. It would be very convenient for me if I could use the `Plotstyle` and `Plotlegends` options to make various 2D plots of projections of my function with `Show`, in a way that allows me to edit it without having to generate the plots again and wait a long time for it to be done.

I'm currently using something like the code below, illustrating my problem.

```
plottz = 
  Plot[
   Evaluate @ Table[z t^2, {t, {.5, .6, .7, .8, 1}}], {z, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
     {Dashing[{.01, .02}], Dashing[{.02, .02}], Dashing[{.04, .02}], 
      Dashing[{.06, .01}], Dashing[{5, .0}]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[
       LineLegend[
         {"t = .5 h", "t = .6 h", "t = .7 h", "t = .8 h", "t = 1 h"}, 
         LabelStyle -> 10], 
       {.3, .7}]];

Show[plottz, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: something like: `Show[plottz /. 
  Join[Thread[
    ColorData[97] /@ Range[5] -> 
     ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[4]], {AbsoluteThickness[_] -> 
     AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    LineLegend[a_, b_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
     LineLegend[a /. AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[4], b, 
      LabelStyle -> 14, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}, opts]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]`?

Answer (score 1):

First I will put kglr's remarkable solution on record.

```
Show[plottz /.
  Join[
    Thread[
      ColorData[97] /@ Range[5] -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[4]],
      {AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
       LineLegend[a_, b_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
         LineLegend[a /. AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[4], b, 
         LabelStyle -> 14, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}, opts]}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: kglr_plot]

IMO this is a solution the would occur only to someone with expertise far beyond mine. As a Mathematica user with more mundane skills, I would settle for a far simpler solution. I would not use `Show` at all. I would precompute a table of values for the function of two variables that is of interest and use `ListLinePlot`. Since the data being displayed has been precomputed, evaluating the plot many times will not be a problem. So one can edit the plot options freely and re-evaluate without worrying about performance.

```
data = With[{dz = 1}, Table[z t^2, {t, {.5, .6, .7, .8, 1}}, {z, 0, 5, dz}]];
ListLinePlot[data,
  DataRange -> {0., 5.},
  PlotStyle ->
    {Dashing[{.01, .02}], Dashing[{.02, .02}], Dashing[{.04, .02}], 
     Dashing[{.06, .01}], Dashing[{5, .0}]},
  PlotLegends ->
    Placed[
      LineLegend[{"t = .5 h", "t = .6 h", "t = .7 h", "t = .8 h", "t = 1 h"},
      LabelStyle -> 10],
    {.3, .7}]]
```

[image: mg_plot1]

And here is an edited version:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  DataRange -> {0., 5.},
  PlotStyle  ->
    ({AbsoluteThickness[5], #} & /@
       {Dashing[{.01, .02}], Dashing[{.02, .02}], Dashing[{.04, .02}], 
        Dashing[{.05, .02}], Dashing[{}]}),
  PlotLegends ->
    Placed[
      LineLegend[{"t = .5 h", "t = .6 h", "t = .7 h", "t = .8 h", "t = 1 h"},
      LabelStyle -> 12],
    {.3, .7}]]
```

[image: mg_plot2]

A list plot is normally very fast, so that even if the OP has a function that evaluates slowly, once the data table is made plots made from the table should display quickly. This means that editing the plot's options will not be a performance issue.